# Sending an XML file back as a response to an HTTPS POST

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Dan, Sung, Leigh:

Thank you all for taking the time to follow up.

Dan:

Yes, we did ask the vendor. We are dealing with their PM for us, and are waiting to hear back from them. He's supposed to consult their tech people. From what you , Sung and Leigh say, it is encouraging, and I can't wait till Tuesday (the finance functional area leader is off on Monday, so we can't get any file pushes till Tuesday) to give all of your recommendations a try.

Thank You all again, sharing your expertise with us is much appreciated. Hope you all have a great weekend, you've certainly helped to improve mine :-)!

Gerry

This is basically a "how to do" question.

**Background:**

We've nearly finished the development of a large application coded in ColdFusion (v11) that interacts with the Sciquest Supplier management system. The last item is returning a response to the vendor, Sciquest, upon receipt of an XML file. This response XML file contains information that is specific to the file they posted to us.

The vendor file is deposited on one of our web servers that is monitored by a ColdFusion directory watcher. Normally, with other apps of this type, we'd post back information to a URL.

However, we were told by our Sciquest contact (exactly what we were told):

> The supplier export response message does not need to be posted to a
>   URL. This is a response back on the same connection that the SciQuest
>   server posted the XML to the Pace server. It would be similar in
>   nature to an ACK message if the process was asynchronous.

Apparently the vendor connection (I assume a http keep alive connection) is not closed properly till a response is received. Can someone provide some instruction on how we would send the XML response file back to the vendor thru their connection to our server, preferably using ColdFusion.

**Update:**

First, Thank You Dan, Sung and Leigh for responding. This is the first time I've ever posted to Stack OverFlow.

The file is sent to us via an HTTPS post by the vendor, Sciquest. Before we can send a response back to the vendor, we need to process the file, because the response XML file requires the new record (from our system) keys along with the "SQI" numbers that start each node section of XML sent to us.

I will try what you all have suggested. I noted that the file sent to us is monitored by a CF Gateway Directory Watcher, that will move the file to a file server, and start the system that will process it.

Would executing a program that outputs the response XML file, as Dan suggested, or one with a CFHeader specification as suggested by Sung, be all that is required to send file information back as a response to the vendor at the end of the main program?

We won't be able to have more files sent to us until Tuesday, as our Finance contact who generates the push on the vendor site client admin will not be in on Monday.

Will update as soon as I can give it a try.

Thank You all again, your assistance is very much appreciated, have a great weekend, and for those of you who are father's, a great Father's Day.

Comment: The simplest solution might actually work.  `<cfoutput>#xmlVariable#</cfoutput>`.

Comment: *vendor file is deposited on one of our web servers* Specifically, how? Are they are "posting" files to some sort of cfm script? If yes, Dan's suggestion is on target.

Comment: *Would executing a program that outputs the response XML file...* In theory yes. As long as the file is processed, and the correct xml response generated, on that same request. Basically it sounds like they need you to process it when it received, not at some later point in time.

Comment: This, `Would executing a program that outputs the response XML file, as Dan suggested, or one with a CFHeader specification as suggested by Sung, be all that is required to send file information back as a response to the vendor at the end of the main program?` is an excellent question.  You should ask it to the vendor.

Answer (score 3):

If the vendor is sending you the XML file via HTTPS POST, as you suggest in your title, then you can just send an XML response back to acknowledge the transmission.  You could easily just send back a response by:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">
[create the XML]
```

I'd think, though, that you'd want to do some sort of a check?  If you use GetHttpRequestData(), you can get back all sorts of good stuff.  Just cfdump it and you'll see.

```
<cfset data = GetHttpRequestData()>
<cfdump var="#data.content#">
```

That'll give you their XML transmission.

Comment: (Edit) ... or depending on what / how it is posted, check the `form` scope. Agreed it sounds like the current process handles files asynchronously. Whereas the sender is expecting them to be processed (or at least somehow acknowledged) synchronously.

Comment: I just had to deal with this, and it's funny -- I used CFX_HTTP to simulate an endpoint call, and even though that call used POST, nothing came through the form scope.  I'm not really sure why.  So then I Googled a bit and came across GetHttpRequestData(), which gave me all sorts of good stuff. :)

Comment: Yes, it all depends on what is posted and how. For example, a request "body" is usually present in `GetHttpRequestData()`, but not the `form` scope. Whereas a "file" typically exists in the `form` scope, but not `GetHttpRequestData()`.  Normally they contain the same data, but as with most things ... it all depends  :)

Comment: *Normally they contain the same data* I should have been more specific ;-) For post requests, `FORM` and GetHttpRequestData().content usually contain the same values.

Comment: Dan, Sung and Leigh: I want to thank all of you for your assistance on this -- what was suggested worked! For the record, this is what was coded (in CFSCRIPT>:  cfheader ( name="Content-Type" , value="text/xml" ) ;
 WriteOutput( SQXResponse ) ;  Thank you all again -- have a great day !